# Print a file and substract in two rows

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print and substract in each two rows from a file

```
toto 30
tata 20
toto 12
tata 6
toto 22
tata 8
```

the output :

```
diff : 10
diff : 6
diff : 14
```

I find a script :

```
FILENAME=$1

while read line
do
  if [ -n "$prevLine" ]
  then
    curLine=$line
    echo $(($curLine - $prevLine))
  fi
  prevLine=($line)
done < $FILENAME
```

I would like to read line+1 to make a range of 2

Comment: You will need to read the file using a loop.

Comment: Your script is on the right lines. Add a line counter which is incremented on each loop pass and check whether `$(($lineNo%2))` is zero to decide when difference is to be calculated and printed.

Comment: I don't understand you solution, Can you have a code to propose me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sole `awk`:

```
<file awk '{if ($1=="toto") old=$2; else if ($1=="tata") print "diff : " old-$2}'
```

where `file` is the file with your data. For each "tata" line the command will print the difference from the previous "toto" line.

Or if it's about odd and even lines (regardless of "toto"/"tata"), then this:

```
<file awk '{if (NR%2==1) old=$2; else print "diff : " old-$2}'
```